# DatePicker week number silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

Can i enable week number in silverlight DatePicker ? And how ?
[image]

Comment: I believe u want a drill down DTP, that is more jQuery oriented & silverlight does not have it. U have to create a custom control OOTB using your own code...

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible with the standard DatePicker control, have you considered adding another control like a label and when the user clicks the date you display the week in the label.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mbAq.png)